# Pagination on top of the questions tab

Tags: feature-request, sorting, pagination

Currently, I have selected 50 questions per page and the pagination bar seem to be too far down the page. Is there a way to make the pagination bar appear on top of the answers list? And the sorting option is also not available. Is there a way to apply sorting on the results so that I can sort the results by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the pagination bar appear on top of the answers list?

As you tagged this question as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I don't feel this feature is required because just by pressing <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> you can go to the end of the page and select the next page.

> Is there a way to apply sorting on the results so that I can sort the results by date

Why on earth you want to sort questions by date? How can you determine that the questions on the particular date would be helpful to you or you can answer the questions which is asked on particular date?

But off-course the [search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search) is available on Stack Overflow. Where you can search (in other word filter not sort) for particular tag, user, word etc.

Comment: `Why on earth you want to sort questions by date? How can you determine that the questions on the particular date would be helpful to you or you can answer the questions which is asked on particular date?` If I want to view the new unanswered questions under my tag which has not been up-voted, viewed by less people, how does one achieve that with out date sorting. I don't want to sort by a particular date. I just want the new questions appear on to of the result.

Comment: @DineshDu - Then go to [unanswered tab](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) and click on [newest tab](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest). And if you want the questions for particular tag then search for that tag like [newest unanswered question tagged with java](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java)